# i wrote this DLL injector in C# but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, dll

So i wrote this DLL Injector from a YouTube tutorial, it has 0 error but it doesn't work.
i've tried injecting hacks with it in Counter Strike:Source, it says the injection succeeded
but nothing was actually injected.

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

```
//form 1
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Tesseract_Injector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process[] PC = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => (long)p.MainWindowHandle != 0).ToArray();
            foreach (Process p in PC)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void inject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Result = Inject(comboBox1.Text, dllpath);

            if (Result == 1) { MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist"); }
            else if (Result == 2) { MessageBox.Show("Process Does Not Exist"); }
            else if (Result == 3) { MessageBox.Show("Injection Failed"); }
            else if (Result == 4) { MessageBox.Show("Injection Succeeded"); }
        }

        private static string dllpath { get; set; }
        private void selectdll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                ofd.Title = "Select DLL file for injection";
                ofd.DefaultExt = "dll";
                ofd.Filter = "DLL Files (*.dll)|*.dll";
                ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
                ofd.CheckPathExists = true;
                ofd.ShowDialog();

                pathbox.Text = ofd.FileName;
                dllpath = ofd.FileName;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void pathbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dllpath = pathbox.Text;
        }

        private void refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] PC = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => (long)p.MainWindowHandle != 0).ToArray();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Process p in PC)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }

        static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpThreadId);
        
        public static int Inject(string PN, string dllpath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(dllpath)) { return 1; }

            uint _procId = 0;
            Process[] _procs = Process.GetProcesses();

            for (int i = 0; i < _procs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_procs[i].ProcessName == PN)
                {
                    _procId = (uint)_procs[i].Id;
                }
            }

            if (_procId == 0) { return 2; }

            if (!SI(_procId, dllpath)) { return 3; }

            return 4;
        }
    
        public static bool SI(uint P, string dllpath)
        {
            IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, P);

            if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO) { return false; }

            IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)dllpath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0x40);

            if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO) { return false; }

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllpath);

            if (WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            CloseHandle(hndProc);

            return true;
        }

        private void settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you asked in the YouTube tutorial comments section?

Comment: yes i did but nobody responded yet so im asking here

Comment: Was `CreateRemoteThread` never actually used in the tutorial?